# How can I show a photo in an imageview in its original aspect ratio?

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview

I would like to show a photo from my phone in an ImageView. This photo is supposed to be shown in it's original aspect ratio. So it should fill up the whole width, but only use as much height as it needs due to it's ratio.
In short: I want to show a photo in an imageview without scaling.

How can I do that? Right now I am using this layout. The problem is that it always scales the photo to fill up the whole screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE for this purpose.
For more detail go through link.
[Android ImageView ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: With `centerInside`, if the image is smaller than the `ImageView` it won't scale up, it would just be centered inside the view. If it is larger it will be scaled down and centered. If you need to scale up smaller images you'd have to use `fitCenter`.

Comment: `fitCenter` is the default setting for ImageView. Wouldn't `layout_height="wrap_content"` solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try put image in `drawable-nodpi` folder and set `wrap_parent` for width and height in ImageView and set link to image in `src`

Comment: wrap_parent?? that does not exist

Comment: i mean `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width to match parent, height to wrap content and to adjust view bounds:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable"/>
```